# How do you implement a FragmentActivity into your FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, listactivity

I have a section my class which is for handling what fragment to load for the FragmentPagerAdapter.  Right now it loads fragments just fine but now I want to implement a FragmentActivity and I am having a problem figuring how to create it as I cant use "newinstance" since its type of Activity, and on top of it, I dont know how to call that FragmentActivity as its different from loading just a Fragment via "newinstance" method. My second tab is the one that I would like to be extended to FragmentActivity.

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Context _context;
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        _context= getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        Fragment f = new Fragment();

        switch(i){
        case 0:
            f=News.newInstance(_context);
            break;  
        case 1:
            f=Info.newInstance(_context);
            break;
        case 2:
            f=Files.newInstance(_context);
            break;
        case 3:
            f=Donate.newInstance(_context);
            break;
        }
        /*

        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

       */
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0: return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
        case 1: return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
        case 2: return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();
        case 3: return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My guess is that I cant use getitem methods as that for only switching Fragments and that I would have to use something like:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, new BasicFragment());
            ft.commit();
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone help point me in the right direction?

This is not supported. It certainly is not possible with `FragmentPagerAdapter`, which only works with fragments.

Comment: I agree, I think you need to convert your FragmentActivity into a Fragment.

Comment: but the activity has to be a FragmentActivity due to needing to setup things which are only possible if you extend it to FragmentActivity

Comment: @user1811306: You cannot put activities into a `ViewPager`. The activity that *contains* the `ViewPager` can be a `FragmentActivity`, and needs to be a `FragmentActivity` if the `ViewPager` will contain fragments.